# C# Disable GridView Header in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can i disable the GridView Headers?
I didn't give them a Name but it still shows "colum1", "colum2"

I already tried:

GridView.ShowHeader = false;
GridView.HeaderRow.Enable = false;

But that didn't work...
So how to solve this problem?

My Code:

```
 GridView gw = new GridView();

 gw.DataSource = tblDetails;
 gw.DataBind();
 gw.CssClass = tblDetailsCssClass;
 gw.RowStyle.Height = 50;           

 panelMain.Controls.Add(gw);
```

CssClass:

```
.Bilddb-tblDetails
    {
        color:black;
        font-size:2em;
        margin: 0 auto; 
        margin-top:20px;   
        display:block;
        width:100%
    }
```

tblDetails:

```
DataTable tblDetails = new DataTable();
        DataColumn colum;
        DataRow row;

        colum = new DataColumn();
        colum.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");            
        tblDetails.Columns.Add(colum);

        colum = new DataColumn();
        colum.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");            
        tblDetails.Columns.Add(colum);


        row = tblDetails.NewRow();
        row[0] = "Title:";
        row[1] = item.Title;
        tblDetails.Rows.Add(row);

        row = tblDetails.NewRow();
        row[0] = "Botanical Name:";
        row[1] = item.BotanicalName;
        tblDetails.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: asp.net or winform ?

Comment: Oh i mean in asp.net

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the GridView control?

Comment: Yes of course - I added it

Comment: And what about the structure of object `tblDetails`?

Comment: I also added this now

Comment: do you want to hide it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to disable the header by using the tag showHeader=false in asp code for the gridview like so: `<asp:Gridview runat=server showHeader=false etc>`

Comment: Oh nice that worked. But why doesnt that work in the cs code?

Comment: Because it is done by programatic way, instead of setting the tags, I had the same problem about three weeks ago